# Can I setup insulation without tearing down walls?

Tags: insulation, diy-vs-pro

My situation is this: I moved into a new apartment last year and my office is the only room that isn't insulated, which is annoying. My daughter's room and her playroom are both insulated as expected. My office door has to be closed when I'm not in there.

Currently, I am using a meager space heater, but I feel like things can be better. Are there insulation boards I can nail to the walls and ceiling? Or should I try and get my landlord to do it?

Comment: How are the windows? I've always been impressed by how effective those heat shrink plastic storm windows are. (Big bonus: by the time you're done hair-drying all the plastic, the room will automatically be a lot warmer, and you'll feel good about your installation.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom I only have one window in my office and it's kinda on the ceiling (like an attic, I'm on the third floor).

Comment: Well, you could just run a hair dryer in your office for an hour, and it would feel warmer, but only for a while...

Comment: I'm thinking I'll buy Dyson's fan heater thingy. After I read some reviews of course.

Answer (score 3):

This is done all the time by insulation contractors. The technique is to drill a series of holes at the top of the wall. They next use a commercial 'blower' that forces insulation into the walls bay. It is a very non-invasive form of insulating because (as you asked) it doesn't necessitate the demolition of existing walls. It is also well with-in a competent DIY-ers capabilities and machines can be rented at most home centers.

Comment: Dense-packing insulation in a wall cavity is a professional skill, not a DIY one. If you try this with rented equipment, you will fail to dense-pack the wall and the more loosely-blown insulation will settle over time, resulting in the top few inches (or more) of each stud bay having no insulation in it.

Answer (score 2):

Read your Lease & definitely run everything past your Landlord. If they're decent or Lease Obligated for improvements they'll likely pay for the materials. But, you'll have to remove & dispose of everything & patch, prime & paint many holes, unless you want to build a tight fitting box frame.

I'd suggest Rigid Foam Boards, 2-layers of 2" thick ones from Lowe's, Home Depot or another Lumber type place. The other option is to get a quote for the Landlord on doing insulation injection. They drill 2" holes in the walls & blow in the insulation. Much more expensive, but you just enjoy & leave with nothing to tidy up.

Comment: No problem & best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please seek a specialists advice on insulating the cavity. I have an old house with the same problem and cavity wall insulation is not an option for me as the cavities apparently contain debris. Filling the cavity while debris is present can cause damp/ventilation problems later. I was advised this by a specialist cavity wall firm. I was told to consider insulation boards on the inside walls, however this will reduce room size slightly.

Comment: I contacted my landlord's agent last night and due to the fact that he just bought the house from the previous owners and already spent $2k fixing things, we're going to wait a bit before bringing this to his attention.

Comment: Good luck - hope all goes well :)